# points3Drgl not displaying

Tags: r, plot, 3d, rgl

I have problem with converting some plots from plot3D to plot3Drgl.

This produces plot without problems

```
require(plot3D)
persp3D(z=matrix(runif(100),nrow=10, ncol=10), clab = "m", shade = 0.2,  
col="#DDDDDD", colkey = FALSE, theta=20, phi=30,  plot=FALSE, zlim = c(0,2))
points3D(x=0.5,y=0.5,z=1.5, col="#FF0000", add=TRUE, plot=TRUE, pch = 20, cex = 2 )
```

The same approach using plot3Drgl throws an error:

```
require("plot3Drgl")
persp3Drgl(z=matrix(runif(100),nrow=10, ncol=10), clab = "m", shade = 0.2,  
col="#DDDDDD", colkey = FALSE, theta=20, phi=30,  plot=FALSE, zlim = c(0,2))
points3Drgl(x=0.5,y=0.5,z=1.5, col="#FF0000", add=TRUE, plot=TRUE, pch = 20, cex = 2 )
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Error in if (dots$add) rgldots$new <- FALSE : argument is of length zero
```

All I want to achieve here is to add single point to 3D surface.

Thanks in advance

MJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an expert on plot3D, but following the help `?points3Drgl` should give you an answer:

> The first step in 3D rgl plotting consists in calling the corresponding 3-D 
>   function from package plot3D with argument plot set to FALSE.
>
> The next step is to create a 3-D rgl plot, by calling plotrgl.

So call your normal `plot3D` functions, with `plot = F` and then simply `plotrgl()`

```
library(plot3D)
library(plot3Drgl)
persp3D(z=matrix(runif(100),nrow=10, ncol=10), clab = "m", shade = 0.2,  
col="#DDDDDD", colkey = FALSE, theta=20, phi=30,  plot=FALSE, zlim = c(0,2))
points3D(x=0.5,y=0.5,z=1.5, col="#FF0000", add=TRUE, plot=FALSE, pch = 20, cex = 2 )
plotrgl()
```

Comment: Thanks! This is obviously a bug that is still there in 2023 (plot3Drgl Version 1.0.4). In my case, `lines3Drgl` had the same error as OP, but `scatter3Drgl` and `text3Drgl` worked.